# Remove the path prefix of the fullpath stored in a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file containing multiple full path

```
/home/pi/1.txt
/home/pi/2.txt
/home/pi/3.txt
```

and I want to get the basename of every file

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

I only know that I can get the every line and use command

```
basename
```

Is it possible to achive my goal more simple? Thank you.

Comment: yes it would be simpler with sed/awk... is that the end goal or you need to do something after getting basename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@try:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'   Input_file
```

Making "/" as field separator and printing the last field of each line.

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Comment: You could select this answer as correct if you think if helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I came up with is this:

```
 basename -a $(<foo.txt)
```

Which works because the process substitution `$()` is the redirected output of the file, which is then split into multiple arguments because of word-splitting. Basename takes multiple args with `-a`.

Note that this doesn't work if there are spaces in the pathnames in the file (because of the said wordsplitting).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I tried your command, it outputed invalid option --‘a’

Comment: The `-a` switch was added on gnu coreutils version 8.16 (2012-03-26) https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD

Comment: ok, thank you so much for your comments, my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*\//,"")||1' file
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that use only shell tools:

```
readarray -t arr <file.txt
echo "${arr[@]##*/}"
```

This assumes that each file is one line (even with spaces). Filenames with newlines will fail as some other structure would be needed in the file.

Comment: thank you so much, this command solved my problem partly. the filename is seperated with space, and my problem can be totally solve by replacing the spaces with new line. The command is "sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' tmp2"